# Subtracting a particular column value by 1 every time when a query is activated

Tags: php, mysql

Table **leave_details** contains the following column

> 1.Employee name
>
> 2.Employee ID
>
> 3.Leavefrom
>
> 4.Leaveto
>
> 5.Leavetype **(Earned leave / sick leave)**
>
> 6.Leavestatus **(Approved/Rejected)**

Whenever a employee applies for leave it will be approved or rejected by the manager. Query for approval

> "UPDATE leave_details join managerlogin on managerlogin.manager_id=leave_details.manager_id SET leave_details.leave_status='Approved' where (employee_id='$myemployee_id' and managerlogin.manager_id= '".$_SESSION['mymanager_id']."' )";

This will change the **leave_status** column as **"Approved"**

I have another table called **employee** which has the overall **Earned leave** and **Sick leave** balance of an employee. Employee table has the following columns

> 1.Employee name
>
> 2.Employee ID
>
> 3.Earned leave (for example 20)
>
> 4.Sick leave (for example 5)

When ever he applies for leave and when the **leave_status** becomes **approved** then the **earned leave** and **sick leave** column in **employee table** should be **decreased by 1** (for example if he applies for **earned leave** then that particular employees column value should be **reduced by 1** [here 20-1=19] , when he applies for the next time [19-1=18] like that it should continue).

How to do it. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am able to change the leave_status column value as Approved (rejected) when the manager approves his/her leave. I have added that query for doing it in my question.check it.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the leave entitlements in the employee table is a bad design - as once changed you have no further references as to what they were; and no temporal reference as to when taken.

So I'd recommend changing the records in the `leave_details` table status to taken - and then count the days taken from the leave_details table to determine how many leave days are remaining, e.g. to find the number of days leave taken in 2011

```
select sum(datediff(leaveto,leavefrom)) as days_leave_taken 
from leave_details 
where employeeid = 1000
      and leavefrom between '2011-01-01' and '2011-12-31 23:59'
```

However if you must update the employee table;

```
UPDATE Employee SET EarnedLeave = EarnedLeave - 1 WHERE EmployeeID = <Id>
```

will do the trick.

Comment: If that is the case then i can create a separate table which is same as employee table and will do what I wanted using that new table. Will this work ?Thanks for your idea..

Comment: don't add a table - use the leave details table - duplication of data is a recipe for problems. See updated answer - I've added a query that will work out leave taken from the leave_details table